# Semantic-ui Table: how to make a column selectable

Tags: semantic-ui

I would like to make table column selectable with semantic-ui. Whereas it is clearly explained in the doc how to make a *row* selectable (https://semantic-ui.com/collections/table.html#selectable-row), I can not figure it out for a column.

Is there a way to achieve it ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>
   <td class="selectable">Selectable entry</td>
</tr>
```

This is the solution i came up with. Im sorry that this might be too late two years after.
So the thing is, that you cant make a row selecteble that easy so I made the single entries selectable. From this selection you can determine which column was clicked in.